# Rider - Log/Output not displayed

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

How do I display the output in a **.NET desktop app in Rider 2021.3.1**? I have tried several variants, nothing is displayed. **Also in the tab "Debug Output" is not displayed**. I **have enabled the setting for output to console**. The curious thing is, when I initialize a console app it works? Is there something special to configure?

[image]

Comment: A GUI application (WinForms/WPF) does not initialize a console at startup, so Rider has no way to get those items written to the console API.